# Firefox: register protocol to open external editor and pass file correctly

Tags: firefox

I want to create file-links to open an external editor from firefox. I have registered a new protocol in firefox using the about:config page:

```
network.protocol-handler.expose.editfile
```

No I can create a link like this:

```
<a href="editfile:N:\test.txt">Edit file</a>
```

Firefox asks me, which application to open for this protocol (in my case I choose Dreamweaver). But then Dreamweaver complains:

> editfile:N:\test.txt has an
>   incorrect filepath.

So Dreamweaver has been told to open '**editfile:N:\test.txt**' and not '**N:\test.txt**'.
I tried this with Notepad++, but same result.

How can I solve this problem, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround or solution:

I registered:

> network.protocol-handler.expose.n

n stands for the drive letter where the file is located on. Now I can open files on N\: with this link:

```
<a href="n:\test.txt">Edit file</a>
```

with Dreamweaver.